# How To Convert Json Array to String Array in C#

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a Json out put as below

```
[
    {
        "eng_trans": "wide, outstretched,"
    },
    {
        "eng_trans": "width,breadth, town, street,earth, country, greatness."
    },
    {
        "eng_trans": "wife, the mistress of the house,"
    },
    {
        "eng_trans": "wide agricultural tract,"
    },
    {
        "eng_trans": "waste land the land which is not suitabie for cultivation."
    }]
```

I need to take only the words with out key and need to form a String List in c#. Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: what have you tried so far, what is not working for you. For example have you tried to use a model class?

Comment: Or do it without a model class, but just using LINQ to JSON - parse it as a `JArray`, then take the `eng_trans` value from each `JObject` in the array.

Comment: Do you have newtonsoft json?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RootObject
{
     public string eng_trans { get; set; }
}
```

This will do the job.

```
  //list to store the words
 List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
 //Convert your json to string.I have already done it for you.
 string json = "[{      \"eng_trans\": \"wide, outstretched,\"  },  {       \"eng_trans\": \"width,breadth, town, street,earth, country, greatness.\"   },  {       \"eng_trans\": \"wife, the mistress of the house,\" },  {       \"eng_trans\": \"wide agricultural tract,\" },  {       \"eng_trans\": \"waste land the land which is not suitabie for cultivation.\"   }]";
 //Add Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget to do this deserialization.
 List<RootObject> eng_trans_List = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

  foreach(RootObject obj in eng_trans_List)
  {
      string[] str =  obj.eng_trans.Split(',');
      foreach(string word in str)
      {
         wordList.Add(word);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.json.dll.

And convert Json string to array.

check this links: 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1074904/How-to-convert-Json-string-to-list-of-objects

Comment: Please provide more information. Link only answers are not considered as good answers. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers